How to become a blockchain Developer
I am interested in the web3 industry, and I want to enter this industry, but I am confused. I come from China, and I want to be a blockchain developer, but my knowledge is limited. I hope someone can give me some advice to make me no longer confused. I want some learning routes, recommend some learning resources, let me away from confusion, thank you very much!

Hi, smart to ask for advice on your learning path. You could think of a simple thing you would want to build,  e.g. a card game, and then start building that by asking people/large language models how to start, then trying that, then getting a lot of errors, and then seeking and/or asking advice on how to solve  each. Then you can retry to make it better with the knowledge you have gained. Or you could find a GitHub project you like and (ask how to) start contributing. Or you could start with a Solidity template and modify or improve it. I hope you enjoy the journey!
